# Solving a First Order Non-Linear Differential Equation of the form $\frac{dy}{dx}=ab-\frac{b}{a}y^2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was wondering how to solve the following DE

$$ \frac{dy}{dx}=ab-\frac{b}{a}y^2 $$

as i cannot seem to find any site or PDF which adresses this specific DE or a similar equation.

Any help is much appriciated. Thank you for your time! :-)

Comment: any own thought? this ODE is not that difficult to solve..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

This is a **separable** first order nonlinear ODE. Search for how to solve these kind of ODEs. :)

Finally, we should came up with

$$\int {\frac{1}{{ab - \frac{b}{a}{y^2}}}dy}  = \int {dx}  + C$$

Answer (score 1):

Use instead $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{b}{a}(a^2-y^2)$ to
separate
$$\dfrac{ady}{a^2-y^2}=bdx,$$
and on which integration is at hand.